# How do i use a cursor correctly

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

With the code below I am trying to search for certain words (SEED WORDS) inside reviews. Then depending on the number of Seed words inside each review I come up with a rating number. There are multiple reviews  per hotel ID. I am trying to get this entered into a Ratings table that has the following columns (HOTEL_ID, CATEGORY_ID,RATING). Each Seed Word has a category associated with it 1,2,3 or 4. The error I have received so far says 'LV_RATE_NUM' must be declared.

```
    DECLARE
lv_hotel NUMBER(4,0);
lv_rate_num NUMBER(4);
lv_rate NUMBER(1,1);
lv_pol NUMBER(1,1);
i number(4,0);
CURSOR cur_rate IS
SELECT a.IDHOTEL, INSTR(a.review,b.seed_words), b.polarity
INTO lv_hotel, lv_rate_num,lv_pol
FROM review a, SEEDWORDS b;
BEGIN
i :=1;
    lv_hotel := i;
 FOR rec_hotel IN cur_rate LOOP
     IF rec_hotel.lv_rate_num  > 0
     THEN lv_rate := lv_rate_num;
     ELSIF rec_hotel.lv_rate_num = 0
     THEN lv_rate_num := 8.6;
     i := i+1;
     END IF;
END LOOP;
INSERT INTO RATINGS
VALUES (lv_hotel, 'CATID',lv_rate);
END;
```

Comment: you assigned 8.6 to your lv_rate_num, use `lv_rate_num NUMBER(4, 1)`;

Comment: I guess you make this more complicated, than it needs to be. The whole thing could likely be done with a simple `INSERT ... SELECT`. And this would also be very, very likely to perform way better than using a cursor. You should explain the logic behind the rating to get help in doing so.

Comment: Is the intention to do a cross join between review and seedwords? You have no join condition specified. And as @stickybit says - unless you are doing homework and the question says "use a cursor to..." then get rid of the cursor. You dont need ti.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `INTO` clause is only used in a singleton SELECT - that is, a SELECT which only returns one row. Your code can be simplified quite a bit:

```
DECLARE
  i         NUMBER := 1;
  lv_hotel  NUMBER := 1;
  lv_rate   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_hotel IN (SELECT INSTR(a.review, b.seed_words) AS LV_RATE_NUM
                      FROM review a
                      CROSS JOIN SEEDWORDS b)
  LOOP
     IF rec_hotel.LV_RATE_NUM > 0 THEN
       lv_rate := rec_hotel.LV_RATE_NUM;
     ELSIF rec_hotel.LV_RATE_NUM = 0 THEN
       lv_rate := 8.6;
       i := i+1;
     END IF;
  END LOOP;

  INSERT INTO RATINGS(HOTEL_ID, CATEGORY_ID,RATING)
    VALUES (lv_hotel, 'CATID', lv_rate);
END;
```

I strongly recommend that you avoid specifying precision and scale on numbers. They are very seldom needed and are a source of potential problems. Note that I'm pretty sure that this still won't do what you intend, but you can use it as a way to get started.

Comment: I tried this out but received the following error:  ORA-01653: unable to extend table SYSTEM.RATINGS by 128 in tablespace SYSTEM
ORA-06512: at line 20

Comment: That says that the tablespace in which one of your tables resides can't be extended. You'll need to talk to your DBAs about this. Either that or move your tables to another tablespace, if you have sufficient privileges. At present your RATINGS table resides in the SYSTEM tablespace. This may not be the best choice. Try running `SELECT * FROM DBA_TABLESPACES` to see if you can find another tablespace to use - then use `ALTER TABLE your_table_name_here MOVE TABLESPACE new_tablespace_name_here`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you have used `into` in cursor query. You can give `alias` to the cursor columns and use that column names in the loop.

```
DECLARE
lv_hotel NUMBER(4,0);
lv_rate_num NUMBER(4);
lv_rate NUMBER(1,1);
lv_pol NUMBER(1,1);
i number(4,1);
CURSOR cur_rate IS
SELECT a.IDHOTEL, INSTR(a.review,b.seed_words) as rate_num, b.polarity as pol
--INTO lv_hotel, lv_rate_num,lv_pol
FROM review a, SEEDWORDS b;
BEGIN
i :=1;
    lv_hotel := i;
 FOR rec_hotel IN cur_rate LOOP
     IF rec_hotel.rate_num  > 0 -- used cursor column alias name 
     THEN lv_rate := lv_rate_num; -- lv_rate_num is not initialized and you are using it here. You must Consider changing the logic
     ELSIF rec_hotel.rate_num = 0
     THEN lv_rate_num := 8.6;
     i := i+1;
     END IF;
END LOOP;
INSERT INTO RATINGS
VALUES (lv_hotel, 'CATID',lv_rate);
END;
```

Your Insert statement is outside the loop so it will insert only one record in the table.

Cheers!!